# Google Analytics cross domain doesnt work

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I have 2 properties, where each of them sits on a different domain.

The analytics work as needed per page view, but cross-domain analytics won't work. when looking at the cookies looks like the client id passes between the Properties

Using gtag and Followed this article,
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain

When using Google Tag Assistant it seems that the source site sends tags as needed but the destination doesnt

Answer (score 0):

To get cross-domain tracking the hits must be sent to the same Property.

Comment: thank you for your response @Michele Pisani.
That's weird as the documentation clearly directs using 2 different tracking ids.

If I send all the hits to one property, how would you recommend differing between their views in the analytic dashboard?

Comment: You can split them at the view level (for example, two views: each with a dedicate filter by host name or page path)